# Restarting a SpriteBatch with the same parameters it started with

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, spritebatch, rendertarget

Is it possible to receive a passed in SpriteBatch that already has had Begin() called, call End() on it because you want to change the RenderTarget, then call Begin() on it again *with the same parameters that were passed in initially*?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to determine exactly which parameters were passed in and which overload of `Begin()` was called; but it is possible to recreate the original state created by that call.

The parameters to `Begin()`, such as `BlendState`, `DepthStencilState`, etc., are actually set on the [`GraphicsDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice_members.aspx). Therefore, it is possible to read (and save) state information from `SpriteBatch.GraphicsDevice`, and re-create it on the next call to `Begin()`

Comment: Cool, that's what I suspected.  Is there a way to see the source for the GraphicsDevice class?

Comment: @GameKyuubi, XNA is close-sourced, but there is MonoGame, which is an open-source, cross-platform port of XNA. You don't need the source strictly to replicate the state though, as GraphicsDevice exposes public properties that contain all the info you need (see the documentation link in my answer)

Comment: Yes, I was analyzing the SpriteBatch class and it uses GraphicsDevice in a way that I want to investigate, specifically regarding GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget().  I'm trying to figure out the limits and order of calls I should be using when handling multiple SpriteBatches and multiple RenderTargets, specifically what property SetRenderTarget sets that SpriteBatch looks at when Begin() is called, since apparently I can't switch a SpriteBatch RenderTarget while the SpriteBatch is active..